# How can I make the mouse cursor disappear in opengl/glut?

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm interested in making the mouse cursor invisible while using opengl + glut, how can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [glutSetCursor function](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutSetCursor.3GLUT.html). It takes one parameter which in this case you can set to the following:

```
glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
```